# Should I delete and repost in another community?

Tags: discussion

I asked https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/23074/can-i-add-tmc-stepsticks-in-parallel-with-existing-a4988 but it seems this community lacks the electronics knowledge to answer it.

Would it be fine to delete and repost in the community Electronics? or somehow to move the question there?

Or should I ask there as well with a link? this solution doesn't look tidy to me.

-> final choice: new question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/702418/can-i-add-tmc-stepsticks-in-parallel-with-existing-a4988

Comment: No, you can't cross-post. The easiest option is to delete it here and then repost elsewhere. Migration requires an agreement and negotiation. Delete the question here, ask on SE.Electric and if you have no luck then you can always delete that question and undelete the question on here. Does that make sense? I've only just seen your question. Looks interesting. (You could always offer a bounty on the question on this site, or you could promote a link to your question on a blog or external site(s), to increase visibility)

Comment: Hmmm, there is certainly more to your question than initially meets the eye (re. current draw *and* the unloaded drivers). I would  not be prepared to post a qualified answer, without being able to try it out first (which I am currently unable to do). Maybe it is better to post on SE.Electronics after all..? Now, I would like to know the answer too :-) (You could post a *similar* question on SE.Electronics, and so long as it is *different* enough (ask about a different aspect, or from a different angle), then maybe you could keep both in place - but this seems to be stretching the rules a bit)

Comment: I'm deleting it, if I ask a different question than I may not get the answer I need

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Good luck. Maybe post the link to the new question here?

Comment: Interestingly, an *apparently* similar question has been asked, [Using dual Y stepper drivers on Marlin / RAMPS 1.4](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/23182/4762). At least, at first glance, it seems similar.